# CSS/HTML centering of several side by side divs

Tags: css, css-float, html, centering

I'm creating a website which needs several blocks of texts and picture placed next to eachother. But I also want them to be centered. I'm using a set size for each of these elements so if someone resizes their screen I want my page to keep changing the number of divs placed next to each other. Normally I would use float:left; for this but that's not going to work as I want my page to be centered to the middle.

so it would look a bit like this:

```
________
|1 2 3 4| 
|  5 6  |
|_______|
```

but when I resize the screen it would look like this:

```
______
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6|
|_____|
```

and if I size up it would look like this:

```
___________
|1 2 3 4 5 |
|    6     |
|__________|
```

currently the css looks like this:

```
 div.child{
width:23%;
float:left;
height:600px;
padding:0px;
min-width:200px;
max-width:230px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
overflow:visible;
display:inline-block;
}
```

and

```
div.parrent{
padding:0px;
border-style:solid;
border-top-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;
}
```

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: give width and heights in percentage!

Comment: Tips: When talking about lengths of '0' it does not matter what the units are, and as such CSS allows you to omit them for brevity and simplicity: `padding:0`. Use the shorthand `border` property for brevity: `border:5px solid`. If you want to use percent widths without padding and borders destroying your calculations, use [`box-sizing:border-box` and others](http://phrogz.net/css/boxsizing.html) so that four `width:25%` fill the parent exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make them all `display:inline-block` and set the parent to have `text-align:center`.

### Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/xdEmz/1/

### Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/E5sHa/2/

[image: Screenshot of Demo 2]

Note that if you want the pictures inside each item to be centered you can either:

- leave the images as `display:inline` (the default) and let `text-align:center` flow through from the parent, and use an explicit `<br>` to force wrapping after them, or
- you can set the pictures to `display:block` (as I have done in the second demo above) and then use `margin:0 auto` to get them horizontally centered within their parent container.

Comment: @user1930011 You're welcome. Note that if you feel that this answer has fully solved your problem you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741). This helps my reputation, your reputation, and helps future visitors to the site find the answers that will help them.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this creating a container with `min-width` and `max-width` and  `text-align:center`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make the individual elements display:inline and container element with text-align center...example here http://psarink.org/gallery.php

Comment: This exact answer was already given two minutes ago. Please try to review the given answers immediately before posting.